# Don't update MS Access database with id

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, sql-update

I try to write a program for updating data with id. When I write number for id (for example id=7), the program is run and works correctly. But when I write label text and convert to number, the code doesn't update and throws an error.

Here is my code:

```
private void yadda_saxla_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connect.Open();  
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "Update Guller set gulun_adi='"+gul_adi.Text+ "', sekil='" + gulun_adi_label.Text + "' where id='"+Convert.ToInt32( id_label.Text)+"'";

    // when i write "id=7" or other number data is update, 
    // but i want update with label text (  Convert.ToInt32( id_label.Text)  )
    // and gives error

    cmd.Connection = connect;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connect.Close();
    disp_data();
}
```

And the error is the following:

[image: error]

What can I do? Thanks...

Comment: Please set your locale to English so the error message you get is in English. In any case, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection: don't concatenate values into a query string (especially not string values obtained from user input).

Comment: [SQL Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Data+Type+Mismatch+in+Expression

Comment: Simply looking at the value of `cmd,CommandText` would have showed you the difference between `id=7` and `id='7'`, which would have been a big hint...

Answer (score 0):

As Others pointed it out in the comments you should **not** concatenate user inputs because it gives an attacking vector for [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). (or at least check for harmful inputs)

Otherwise the solution, I think, is that you should remove the ' because at the moment the command currently parsed as a varchar.
This part `where id='"+Convert.ToInt32( id_label.Text)+"'"` becomes `where id='7'` instead of `where id=7`

So unless your ID is stored as a varchar, this line should be changed

```
cmd.CommandText = "Update Guller set gulun_adi='"+gul_adi.Text+ "', sekil='" + gulun_adi_label.Text + "' where id='"+Convert.ToInt32( id_label.Text)+"'";
```

to

```
cmd.CommandText = "Update Guller set gulun_adi='"+gul_adi.Text+ "', sekil='" + gulun_adi_label.Text + "' where id="+Convert.ToInt32( id_label.Text);
```

Comment: What is the SQL injection part? I know SQL query.

Comment: There is a link in my answer, basically a hacking technique. The user enters a string that modifies your query.

Comment: In your case, imagine that the "gul_adi.Text" contains something like " 1' Drop Database WhatEver -- " If you would have a what ever database the code would delete it and the last part -- comments out the rest so the syntax would be correct. Also would set everything in the table to 1, which can be another issue.